# Is there a way to show endpoint present in my maven dependencies in swagger-ui

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to list all the endpoints in my application including some of the endpoints present in the dependent libraries using Swagger. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Swagger automatically fetch all the endpoints that are present in the package that you have mentioned in the configuration. You have to mention the base package properly.

Comment: Hi, I have tried with RequestHandlerSelectors.any(), which I believe include the packages from the maven libraries also. I am not sure about that. But still I am not getting those end points in the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Swagger automatically fetch all the endpoints according to configuration. You have to mention the base url:

```
return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/admin/**"))
            .build()
            .useDefaultResponseMessages(false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

But I am already tried with  

return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
          .select()                                  
          .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())              
          .paths(PathSelectors.any())                          
          .build();

where I have used PathSelectors.any(), But I am getting only the endpoint I have exposed in my custom controllers. I need to see my whole available endpoints(including those exposed in my maven dependencies).